# Bootstrap datepicker partially hidden

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I refer to the following Bootstrap date picker:

https://hackthestuff.com/article/how-to-use-bootstrap-datepicker-in-your-website

I constructed a sample web page with a navbar, which contains a date picker. Here is the complete HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline row">
                <input type="text" class="form-control my-1 mr-sm-2" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true"
                    id="datepicker" style="width: 120px" value="12/04/2020" onkeydown="return false">
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- If I comment out the whole div here, the whole calender will be visible. -->
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 80px">
        <!-- Other stuff -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker();
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

When the page is rendered on both IE and Chrome, the top of the calendar is not visible due to a shift in the position of the calendar.

[image]

But if I remove the div below the navbar, the whole calendar will be visible:

[image]

How can I resolve this problem? I need the div below the navbar as it contains the main things for the page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `margin-top: 80px;` to `padding-top: 80px;>`

Because you added a margin-top of 80px the calendar does not display correctly.

Here's a codeply with the calendar displaying correctly and keeping the container.
https://www.codeply.com/p/RDohpwmwAV

Comment: Thanks. I had actually figured out earlier that it was "margin-top: 80px;" that caused the problem. An alternate solution is to change "fixed-top" for the navbar to "sticky-top".

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out!